# Haxe/openfl textfield memory leak

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, textfield, haxe, openfl

I was learning some Haxe with openfl and adding images and text to the screen and did so.

I started by creating a project through command line with openfl, added an update frame event listener, a picture and text using

```
addChild(myText);
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, update);
bonzi = new Bitmap(Assets.getBitmapData("assets/bonzi.jpg"));
addChild(bonzi);
```

and in the update() method I put:

```
bonzi.rotation += 4;
myText.text = bonzi.rotation;
```

This works like expected, bonzi.jpg rotating around top-left corner and  in the same corner a textfield displaying the rotation.

Now  here's the problem: If I let this run for ~30 sec the program has eaten up 1.8 Gb of my memory and runs then very slowly, hogging now exactly 1863.6 Mb of memory. Eventually myText disappeared after the program ran really slow for about another 20 sec, making bonzi rotate almost normally but still hogging the same amount of memory. Even if I add

```
if (bonzi.rotation >= 360) bonzi.rotation -= 360;
```

to the update-loop to make sure the rotation keeps within the [0;360] range, same thing happens.

Strangely, though, if I change anything so that myText does not **change** in the update method memory usage stays normal (15-30 Mb) e.g. changing Std.string(bonzi.rotation) to Std.string("Hi") or bozi.rotation += 4 to bozi.rotation = 4.

I'm at loss to why this happens. This is very inconvenient since I plan to use text-fields a lot in the future.

EDIT: My full code run through openfl via cpp - test

```
package;

import openfl.display.Sprite;
import openfl.display.Bitmap;
import openfl.Assets;
import openfl.text.TextField;
import openfl.events.Event;
import openfl.system.System;

class Main extends Sprite {

    public var bonzi:Bitmap;
    public var myText:TextField = new TextField();

    public function new() {
        super();

        addChild(myText);
        stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, update);

        bonzi = new Bitmap(Assets.getBitmapData("assets/bonzi.jpg"));
        addChild(bonzi);
        bonzi.rotation = 260;
        myText.text = Std.string(bonzi.rotation);
    }


    public function update(e:Event):Void {
        bonzi.rotation += 4;
        if (bonzi.rotation >= 180) bonzi.rotation -= 360;

        myText.text = Std.string(bonzi.rotation);
    }   
}
```

Comment: Interesting. Could you provide the exact code you were testing?

Answer (score 2):

it doesn't seem to be an issue from your code to me...

You should file an issue at there github repositories :

https://github.com/openfl/openfl/issues

Please include a complete runnable sample so that it would be easier for them to take action.